# Экспорт SharePoint List как xlsx файл

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Пишу библиотеку для взаимодействия с шарпоинтом и на строке `worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex].Value = item[field.InternalName];` ловлю такой эксепшен: `The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested`.

```
public static bool ExportToExcel(this List list, ClientContext context, string outputPath)
        {
            // Load list items
            CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
            ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(items);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            // Create new Excel package
            using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(list.Title);

                context.Load(list.Fields);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                // Add column headers
                int columnIndex = 1;
                foreach (var field in list.Fields)
                {
                    if (!field.Hidden)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[1, columnIndex].Value = field.Title;
                        columnIndex++;
                    }
                }

                // Add data rows
                int rowIndex = 2;
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    columnIndex = 1;
                    foreach (var field in list.Fields)
                    {
                        if (!field.Hidden)
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex].Value = item[field.InternalName]; // здесь исключение
                            columnIndex++;
                        }
                    }
                    rowIndex++;
                }

                // Save Excel package to file
                FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(outputPath + list.Title + ".xlsx");
                excelPackage.SaveAs(excelFile);
                return true;
            }
        }
```